# Qt5: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QApplication'

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5

System: 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) x64

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.5.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 120, 85, 26))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get the following error:

```
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QApplication'
```

Basically, I designed the GUI with the Qt5 and then used pyuic5. I already installed PyQt5, not sure if the installation went through as expected.

UI Design:

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does this: `dir(QtGui)` give you?

Comment: I just updated the post for further reference.

Comment: There are several problems with this code: `QApplication` is in `QWidgets`, the `import sys` statement is missing, `Ui_Form` should probably inherit a Qt class `QWidget`?, `ex.setupUi(ex)` has to be called before the `ex.show()`.

Comment: Let me try again. I used from a practice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure how your main function was generated. I tried to replicate it with what seems to be the same version of pyuic5. I am calling it with the commandline `pyuic5 -x untitled.ui` (where the ui as in your  case just contains a PushButton in a Widget). The `-x` option has the effect: 'The generated Python code includes a small amount of additional code that creates and displays the GUI when it is executes as a standalone application.' (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) The result I get is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.5.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which has a different main function. The rest of the code is equivalent.

Comment: You right, the import sys statement is missing. However, this code was generated by pyuic5... pyuic5 test.ui > test.py

Answer (score 6):

In PyQt5 the `QApplication` method is not supported to be used with `QtGui` instead it can be used with `QtWidgets`. Try to rewrite your code like

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

if using PyQt5 instead of PyQt4. It should probably work.
Other attributes like which i know `QStyleFactory` has also changed to be used with `QtWidgets`.

Hope this may solve your problem.